# How do I retrieve all the reviewers in the PR in a GitHub Probot

Tags: node.js, typescript, octokit, probot

how do I retrieve all the reviewers in a pull request from `Probot`? I am using `typescript`. I am also listening on `pull_request` event type in Probot. I think I need to call `context.github.pullRequests.getReview` to get the list of reviewers, but since I am new to `NodeJs` and `typescript`, I am not sure how to invoke the below function. Any inputs?

Also, `getReview` accepts the parameter `{owner:,repo:,number:, review_id:}`, in my case I just have the `pr_number`.

```
 getReview(
      params: Github.PullRequestsGetReviewParams,
      callback?: Github.Callback<
        Github.Response<Github.PullRequestsGetReviewResponse>
      >
    ): Promise<Github.Response<Github.PullRequestsGetReviewResponse>>;
```

Comment: I tried `context.github.pullRequests.listReviewRequests(context.issue());`, but this will give reviewers added during PR creation. How do I get all the reviewers (added during PR creation, self-requested and also added by another reviewer, etc)

Comment: I agree that this is rather confusing. I tested the [List reviews on a pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#list-reviews-on-a-pull-request) endpoint but it only lists the requests, not the reviews that have been actually done.

I would recommend to contact support about it, it might be a bug, or the documentation needs to be updated

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, the [List reviews on a pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#list-reviews-on-a-pull-request) does not return the reviews, but instead the review requests.

I could not find a REST API endpoint, but you could send a GraphQL Request instead

```
    query {
        resource(url:"https://github.com/probot/probot/pull/870") {
            ... on PullRequest {
                title
                url
                reviews(first: 100) {
                    nodes {
                        author {
                            login
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

you can use the `context.graphql` method for that. See https://github.com/octokit/graphql.js for its API. Make sure you use the latest version of Probot (current 9.2.4)

Answer (score 0):

For us, it is in the `requestedReviewer` object of `reviewRequests` using `pullRequests` query.

One thing to notices is the reviewer could be `User` or `Team` so we need to leverage the spread operator `... on User/Team` for them to get different fields.

```
query {
  compass: repository(owner: "YourOrg", name: "YourRepo") {
    pullRequests(states: [OPEN], last: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          title,
          updatedAt,
          url
          mergeable
          author {
            login
          },
          reviewRequests(first: 10) {
            nodes{
              requestedReviewer{
                ... on User {
                  userName: name
                  login                  
                }
                ... on Team {
                  teamName: name
                }
              },

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```